# How do i enable javascript in a .html document?

Tags: javascript, html, css, copy, httrack

I wanted to learn a lil bit of website coding so I decided I want to see how a website is written. I used HTTrack Website Copier to copy a website and then i opend the index.html document. Now I saw a row where it says "-- Please enable Javascript --</p". How do I enable javascript to see what normaly would stand in that row? Also i dont have any html oder css file in the folder where HTTrack put the index.html into. Is that normal?

I dont know what to do about this cause i started 2days ago^^

Comment: Which operating system and browser do you use? For example, you can enable JavaScript in Safari via Settings->Security. Just google: "Enable JavaScript in <your_os_and_browser>". It is important that you open `index.html` in your browser afterwards, not in the text editor/IDE.

Comment: I don't know anything about HTTracker (I guess it is a browser extension). The line doesn't mean that you have to enable Javascript to see the contents, this just defines what will be displayed on the browser window, literally. I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do, if you just want to learn web development, watch this crash course, it is a good starting point: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UB1O30fR-EE&t=1413s

Comment: Anyways, just click on the lock icon in the URL bar, and open Site Settings. Unblock Javascript, but again, that doesn't do anything in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, that page you copied is referencing a JavaScript file that you didn't download with the HTML file. Look through your HTML for a `<script src="...">...</script>` tag or something similar; that's the missing file.  Same goes for the CSS, except that will be near the top with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">`.

HTML is how the page is laid out.  CSS is how the page looks (font sizes, colors, etc).  JavaScript is how the page works (interactive features).  I'd start with just basic HTML, you're kind of jumping in on the deep end.  Codecademy has great (and free) introductory courses that should help you understand what you're looking at better.